# How to set 24h in Calendar method on Android?

Tags: android, android-calendar, realm

I want develop TODO-List application with Realm Database, this application user can set Title, Date and time for Task/Todo . 
I want when user set Date, hour save to database with 24h instead of am/pm. 
for example : i want show hour this formatting 17:34 , but show me 05:34 !

I use this codes, but show me am/pm formatting.

**Calendar method** and save to database :

```
// Calendar Method
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dialog_date.getDay()-1);
calender.set(Calendar.MONTH, dialog_date.getMonth()-1);
calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, dialog_date.getYear());
calender.set(Calendar.HOUR, dialog_date.getHour());
calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dialog_date.getMinute());

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Task_Provider task_provider = new Task_Provider(addTask, now, calender.getTimeInMillis(), false);
```

**Code 1 :**

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy" + "\n" + "      " + "hh:mm");

        public void setDate(long when_date) {
            card_date.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(when_date)));
        }
    }
```

**Code 2 :**

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy" + "\n" + "      " + "kk:mm");

        public void setDate(long when_date) {
            card_date.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(when_date)));
        }
    }
```

Code 3 :

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy" + "\n" + "      " + "HH:mm");

        public void setDate(long when_date) {
            card_date.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(when_date)));
        }
    }
```

but this code not work for me! 
How can save 24h in calendar method on Android? tnx all <3

Comment: Just make a custom calendar model that holds ints and store that in realm

Comment: @TimCastelijns, can you help me more?

Comment: When setting the hour on a 24h-clock `Calendar`, you need to use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, not `Calendar.HOUR`.

Comment: @MikeM. , thank you man. it's ok